# Need help on understanding pointers in c

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, concept

I'm having trouble understanding pointers concept and below is the code. Why the swap(&a1, &a2) out puts the -5, 6 rather than 6, -5 ? The values are already swap right?

```
void swap(int *ptr1, int *ptr2){

     int temp;

      temp = *ptr1;
      *ptr1 = *ptr2;
      *ptr2 = temp;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    void swap(int *ptr1, int *ptr2);
    int a1 = -5;
    int a2 = 6;
    int *p1 = &a1;
    int *p2 = &a2;

    NSLog(@" a1 = %i, a2 =%i", a1, a2); // out puts: -5, 6

    swap(p1,p2);
    NSLog(@" a1 = %i, a2 =%i", a1, a2); // out puts: 6, -5

    swap(&a1, &a2);
    NSLog(@" a1 = %i, a2 =%i", a1, a2); // out puts: -5, 6
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your first call to swap() swapped the two values, and the second call swapped them back.

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping the same thing every time(sorta) so first you swap them, and then you swap them back.
a1 stored the value -5 at address1 (an address is a location in memory)
a2 stores the value 6 at addess2
p1 points to addres1
p2 points to address2
swapping p1 and p2
Here you take the value of the item stored at address1 and switch it with the value of the item at address2.
so now
address1 holds the value 6 and address2 holds the value -5
Here p1 and p2 still point at the same addresses and a1 and a2 still return values from the same addresses but the values have been swapped.
swapping &a1 and &a2
Swapping &a1 and &a2 does the same thing, the & returns the addresses as pointers, which you them pass to the swap function. Swap takes to pointers and swaps the values of the addresses they point to.

Basically, pointers point to a memory location. Your swap function takes to memory locations and exchanges the data stored in them, it does not change what memory address they are pointing to. So in both cases you are sending the same addresses, so you swap the same to location twice.

Comment: so are you saying that the second swap call swaps the values back from the first swap call?

Comment: What I'm saying is that swap takes two pointers to locations(addresses) in memory and swaps the values stored at those locations. In the first case you call swap(p1, p2) where p1 is the address of a1 and p2 is the address of a2. In the second case you call swap(&a1, &a2) where &a1 is the address of a1 and &a2 is the address of a2. These two calls are equivalent so the first call swaps them and the second swaps them again, putting them back in their original location.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example just to get a feeling about pointers...

```
int i = 2; // i == 2
int *p = &i; // p == 0x00AB (say memory addres of i is 171)
int *q = p;  // q == 0x00AB q and p have the same value
```

p == q is true

*p == 2 is true

*p == *q is true

```
p = NULL;      // initializes the pointer, which is a good practice
if (*p == 2) { // don't do this as it can cause error or unpredictable results
```

i == 2 is still true irrespective of what you did with your pointer variable

Pointer variables could be seen or thought of as holding "special" integer values, they store a memory address, which usually is 32-bit number (unless you are running on a 64-bit address computer).

Comment: "i == 2 is still true irrespective of what you did with your pointer variable" - not quite, `*p = 42` would make `i` have the value `42`

Comment: @CRD You are providing a good example of the difficulties of understanding pointers. In these code snippets, p is the pointer,  *p is the way to see what p is pointing to. What I tried to say with the simple examples above is that if you manipulate your POINTER VARIABLE (as in setting p = NULL;) it won't affect the value it was pointing to and so *p is no longer equal to 2. Hope I made it clear.